# untracked ".#file" in a git repository?

Tags: git, auto-save

**Q:** where do untracked `.#files` come from when working in a git repository?

When working on file `example.txt` in a `git` repository, I occasionally get an untracked file showing up in status titled `.#example.txt` (that is, dot-hash-filename).  (This happens both in `magit's` status buffer and when running `git status` from the command line, so it seems to be Emacs-related but not `magit`-related.)

What is causing the appearance of untracked files of this sort?  It does not appear to be a standard auto-save file (or at least I've never seen the `.#` prefix before.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are [lock files](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Locks.html).

> When two users edit the same file at the same time, they are likely to
>   interfere with each other. Emacs tries to prevent this situation from
>   arising by recording a file lock when a file is being modified. Emacs
>   can then detect the first attempt to modify a buffer visiting a file
>   that is locked by another Emacs job, and ask the user what to do. The
>   file lock is really a file, a symbolic link with a special name,
>   stored in the same directory as the file you are editing. (On file
>   systems that do not support symbolic links, a regular file is used.)

To disable:

```
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

How I knew this:

I've seen these before, but I couldn't remember what they were or how I disabled them. A simple search in the Emacs source code found the file `src/filelock.c`, which reminded me:

```
ag --cc '\.#'
```

Comment: I should add that you probably _shouldn't_ disable lockfiles. They've been added to Emacs for a reason, the same reason that lockfiles were implemented for vim, LibreOffice, Microsoft Office and a host of other programs. Working around them is probably better than banishing them. You could easily just `.gitignore` them for example.

Comment: @PythonNut you should post the gitignore piece as an answer. That's exactly the right idea.

Comment: @AlanShutko my reservation is that it really doesn't answer the OP's _question_ (i.e. "what are these things and where do they come from"). It's really just a fragment of advice.

Comment: Nice explanation, particularly because you explained how you found the answer.

Comment: @PythonNut: your point about `.gitignore` is probably the better way to deal with the lockfiles than turning them off.  Although I'm accepting nanny's answer because it answers the question I posed, I'd be happy to +1 your comment if you change it to an answer as well.

Comment: .gitignore is not always a viable approach - for example, (as a JS dev), if you use mocha for testing, and are watching a directory then it will attempt to run the lock file as a test.

Answer (score 5):

Nanny's answer is correct, but I'd like to add that disabling lockfiles is not recommended.

They've been added to Emacs for a reason, the same reason that lockfiles were implemented for vim, LibreOffice, Microsoft Office and a host of other programs. Multiple programs editing the same file can be a real pain, leading to mass confusion and possibly nuclear war (okay, maybe not). Rather than disabling the feature, I would suggest working around the files instead.

For example, you can easily add the line

```
.#*
```

to your `.gitignore` if they annoy you.