# Auto save is disabled but emacs is making files in the format .#file-name

Tags: files, auto-save

I set auto save to nil after discovering this, but they keep popping up. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

It's not the typical #filename#, it's making a dotfile .#

Comment: Those are lock files. See my answer here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/8193/untracked-file-in-a-git-repository/8194#8194

Comment: @nanny Thank you so much. I need to disable them completely...but only for a certain directory. Is there any way I could do that?

Comment: Unless you reimplement that functionality in Emacs Lisp, no.

Comment: @AR7 You could use a `.dir-locals.el` file: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html

Comment: That wouldn't work that well because `create-lockfiles` isn't a buffer-local variable.

Comment: @wasamasa Ah, you're right, thanks.